# Bash: Find exclude directory error

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I have this folder structure:

```
incoming/
Printing/
    |------ done/
    \------ error/
```

The server is monitoring the `Printing` folder, waiting for `.txt` files to appear in it.  When a new file is detected, it sends it to a printer and moves the file to `done` on success or to `error` on failure.

The script I am working on must do the following: scan the `incoming` directory for files, and transfer them one by one to the `Printing` folder. I started with this script I found here on StackOverflow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
  target="/var/www/test";
  dest="/var/www/incoming";

  find $dest -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -r | while IFS= read -r file; do
    counter=0;
    while [ $counter -eq 0 ]; do
      if find   "$target" -maxdepth 0 -mindepth 0 -empty | read; then 
        mv -v "$file" "$target" && counter=1; 
      else
        echo "Directory not empty: $(find "$target" -mindepth 1)"
        sleep 2; 
      fi;
    done;
  done
done
```

The problem is that it detects the two subfolders `done` and `error` and refuses to copy files, always emitting the "Directory not empty" message.
I need a way to make the script ignore those folders.

I tried variations on the `find` command involving `-prune` and `! -path`, but I did not find anything that worked.  How can I fix the `find` command in the inner loop to do as I require?

Comment: This is just a guess but should `mindepth` be 1?  On my machine the `find` man page says: `Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative  integer). '-mindepth 1' means process all files except the command line arguments.`

Comment: Nope, @7Reeds. `-mindepth 1` together with `-maxdepth 0` would not make sense.  And `-maxdepth 0` is appropriate, because the point is that `find` should test the named directory only (with the `-empty` predicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command at issue is this:

```
find "$target" -maxdepth 0 -mindepth 0 -empty
```

Start by recognizing what it does:

- it operates on the directory, if any, named by `"$target"`
- because of `-maxdepth 0`, it tests *only* that path itself
- the `-empty` predicate matches *empty* regular files and directories
- (the `-mindepth 0` is the default; expressing it explicitly has no additional effect)

Since your expectation is that the target directory will *never* be empty (it will contain at least the two subdirectories you described), you need an approach that is not based on the `-empty` predicate.  `find` offers no way to modulate what "empty" means.

There are multiple ways to approach this, some including `find` and others not.  Since `find` is kinda heavyweight, and it has a somewhat obscure argument syntax for complex tests, I suggest an alternative: `ls` + `grep`.  Example:

```
# File names to ignore in the target directory
ignore="\
.
..
done
error"

# ...

while /bin/true; do
  files=$(ls -a "$target" | grep -Fxv "$ignore")

  if [ -z "$files" ]; then
    mv -v "$file" "$target"
    break
  else
    # non-ignored file(s) found
    echo "Directory not empty:"
    echo "$files"
    sleep 2
  fi
done
```

Things to note:

- the `-a` option is presented to `ls` to catch dotfiles and thereby match the behavior of `find`'s `-empty` predicate.  It is possible that you instead would prefer to ignore dotfiles, in which case you can simply drop the `-a`.
- the `F` option to `grep` specifies that it is to match fixed strings (not patterns) and the `-x` option tells it that it must match whole lines.  The `-v` option inverts the sense of the matching, so those three together result in matching lines (filenames) other than those specified in the `ignore` variable.
- capturing the file list in a variable is more efficient than recomputing it, and avoids a race condition in which a file is detected just before it is moved.  By capturing the file list, you can be sure to recapitulate the exact data on which the script bases its decision to delay.
- It is possible for filenames to include newlines, and carefully crafted filenames containing newlines could fool this script into thinking the directory (effectively) empty when in fact it isn't.  If that's a concern for you then you'll need something a bit more robust, maybe using `find` after all.

Comment: in your version, in the first part files to be ignore, done and error are folders, is ok like this to exclude them?

Comment: Also i need the counter to stop the moving proces until the new mouved file is procesed and place in done folder or error

Comment: @OlaMihai, it does not matter for this purpose that `done` and `error` are folders instead of ordinary files.

Comment: @OlaMihai, your use of `counter` in your original script is to break out of the inner loop after moving a file -- no more and no less.  My version accomplishes this with a `break` command, instead.  That exhibits the same behavior, but is cleaner and clearer.

Comment: Is working but I get an error at  if -z  ,,command not fount"

Comment: And is give something like folder is not empty but is not list any file

Comment: Solved, was missing [ ] for the if -z statement. Thanks a lot.